# Implementing geolocation in android

Tags: android, geolocation

I am making an app in which i an getting latitude and longitude details as follows:

```
Latitude   30.7281826
Longitude  76.8475601
```

But i want the details , means  lat and long details in degrees and minutes and so on

[image: IT contains lat and long details in degrees and minutes and so on]

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the link http://www.neptuneandco.com/~jtauxe/bits/LatLonConvert.java

```
public class LatLongConvertor {
public static Data fromDec2DMS(double dfDecimal) {
    double dfDegree; // degree part of degrees/minutes/seconds
    double dfMinute; // minute part of degrees/minutes/seconds
    double dfSecond;
    double dfFrac;
    double dfSec;

    // Get degrees by chopping off at the decimal
    dfDegree = Math.floor(dfDecimal);
    // correction required since floor() is not the same as int()
    if (dfDegree < 0)
        dfDegree = dfDegree + 1;

    // Get fraction after the decimal
    dfFrac = Math.abs(dfDecimal - dfDegree);

    // Convert this fraction to seconds (without minutes)
    dfSec = dfFrac * 3600;

    // Determine number of whole minutes in the fraction
    dfMinute = Math.floor(dfSec / 60);

    dfSecond = dfSec - dfMinute * 60;

    // Fix rounoff errors
    if (Math.rint(dfSecond) == 60) {
        dfMinute = dfMinute + 1;
        dfSecond = 0;
    }

    if (Math.rint(dfMinute) == 60) {
        if (dfDegree < 0)
            dfDegree = dfDegree - 1;
        else
            // ( dfDegree => 0 )
            dfDegree = dfDegree + 1;

        dfMinute = 0;
    }
    GeoData data = new GeoData();
    data.dfDegree = dfDegree;
    data.dfMinute = dfMinute;
    data.dfSecond = dfSecond;
    return data;
}
}

class GeoData {
    double dfDegree;
    double dfMinute;
    double dfSecond;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting desired output.My code is as follows: public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
  {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {
   try 
   {
   latitude = loc.getLatitude();
   longitude = loc.getLongitude();
   altitude=loc.getAltitude();
   
   loc.getAccuracy();
   latitudee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitudee);
   latitudee.setText(""+latitude);
   
   longitudee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitudee);
   longitudee.setText(""+longitude);
    
      }
   catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you should have a look at the SensorManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

here is a nice sample, look at onAccuracyChanged() :

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/43.html

Add This code in ur file for conversion :
http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2009/05/convert-decimal-degrees-to-degrees.html

This links help u but if any more u want comment it so i can be more clear can help u

Comment: My code is as follows: public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener { public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) { try { latitude = loc.getLatitude(); longitude = loc.getLongitude(); altitude=loc.getAltitude(); loc.getAccuracy(); latitudee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitudee); latitudee.setText(""+latitude); longitudee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitudee); longitudee.setText(""+longitude); } catch (Exception e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: i want to know which link code u r using ? n if u r using then please see ur code analyse n paste in it

Comment: I am using  http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2009/05/convert-decimal-degrees-to-degrees.html code . Please embed this link code in mine